# DataTables, Ember.js and Views inside a <td>

Tags: javascript, ember.js, datatables

I'm curious if anyone has ever tried to implement a view within side a  using data tables? I'm loading the data and dataTables through didInsertElement. I'm currently appending an "edit" and "delete" button inside a td for each record so the user can click and edit the record which takes them to a new page or delete the record. This is done currently by adding HTML in the model and sending the event to a controller. As my understanding of Ember has grown I see the better way of doing this would be to have the column that holds the "edit" and "delete" be individual views that are triggered.

Has anyone done this before? The problem with implementing it in the templates is each time the application loads there could be an unknown number of columns depending on the API hook that I'm pulling from.

Answer (score -2):

This should get you close. Let's say you know you want to use views for columns 0 and 1, and let everything else render normally. Basically, in your datatables def, you need to add post-processing to the row render to wire up your views/templates. Here is an example leveraging jQuery to find the appropriate columns (my EmberJS is a bit primitive, but I believe you can get the gist):

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull){
  var myView0 = Ember.View.create({ <view def goes here> })
  var myView1 = Ember.View.create({ <view def goes here> })
  myView0.appendTo($("td:eq(0)", nRow));
  myView1.appendTo($("td:eq(1)", nRow));
  return nRow;
}
```

Note that you do need to be careful about performance. If you are displaying hundreds/thousands of rows at a time, and you are listening for events individually on each of those rows, you could pay a performance penalty, it just depends on how you lay things out.

Comment: This doesnt address the question regarding the embedded views

Comment: I was referring to an Ember view

Comment: Well, now you've hit the limits of my understanding of Ember. What I have now should attach an ember view to whatever column you want within the data table. I can delete my answer if you think that isn't enough.